# Passing to constructor or creating

Tags: oop

Though both are correct but which of the following is the recommended way:

```
public class MyService(MyRepository ...) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
public class MyService() {
    myRepository = CreateMyRepository();
}

protected MyRepository CreateMyRepository() {
    ...
}
```

The former would mean that that ought to be a public getter for the repository, which defeats the purpose of allowing only the service to control the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one. That is loosely coupled. It means that you can decide how to instantiate `MyRepository` or even provide a subclass to override behaviour. It also helps to instantiate `MyRepository` only once and use same instance in multiple places.

Also, see more
[What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement but I would recommend as shown below example.

**Public Constructor** useful in Dependency Injection.

**Protected Constructor** can be used its own class and subclasses(Useful in ***Singleton Design Pattern***). Its also useful Constructor for an Abstract class.

**Private Constructor** can be used in its own class and ensures there should not be more than one object (useful in ***Singleton Design Pattern***, ***Builder Design Pattern***).

```
 class MyService {
      private MyRepository myRepository;

      public MyService(MyRepository myRepository){
          this.myRepository= myRepository;  

      }

      public String getMyRepository() { return myRepository; }

       public void setMyRepository(MyRepository myRepository)
       {    
       this.myRepository= myRepository;
      }

    }
```